Can anyone help e with FFMPEG on Centos 7
I have a script that requires FFMPEG but I cant seem to get it working on my Centos 7 server the script gives the following error:
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x252ac20] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (av01 / 0x31307661), none, 1920x1080, 4199 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
/home/ivebo/public_html/admin-panel/videos/test.mp4: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/ivebo/public_html/admin-panel/videos/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomav01iso2mp41
    title           : Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
    artist          : Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
    composer        : Sacha Goedegebure
    encoder         : Lavf58.63.100
    comment         : Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net
    genre           : Animation
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4201 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: none (av01 / 0x31307661), none, 1920x1080, 4199 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
No decoder for stream #0:0, filtering impossible
Error opening filters!.

When i type FFMPEG in CLI it says following:
This is my FFMPEG install on Centos 7
FFMPEG
[root@bakcenterline ~]# ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
[root@bakcenterline ~]#

I followed this tutorial: https://bobcares.com/blog/ffmpeg-install-centos/
Any experts out there that can dianose this problem?  It would be much apriciated!

The guide you linked deals with the ffmpeg installation but says nothing about codecs. The error message is about missing codecs.
